# NSregularExpression and password

Tags: objective-c, ios

i would like to test the validity of my password with `NSRegularExpression`. my password should have 5 caractèers or more. how i can do this? thanks

```
NSRegularExpression *passwordRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"???"
                                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                         error:&error];
```

Comment: What do you mean by 5 characters: Whatever characters, letters, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the length of the password string.

```
BOOL validPassword = password.length >= 5;
```

As to the regex, you can use this one: `@".{5,}"`.

```
NSRegularExpression *passwordRegex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@".{5,}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
int numberMatches = [passwordRegex numberOfMatchesInString:password options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, password.length)];
BOOL validPassword = numberMatches > 0;
```

If you want only to accept some types of characters, then you can use the following regexes:

1. `@"^[A-Za-z]{5,}$`": letters only
2. `@"^[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}$"`: letters and numbers only

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression to do that.  If you are comparing it against a string, just use this:

```
if(string.length < 5)
{
     [user getAngry:WithWeapon:];
}
```